# PDE $yu_{yy} + u_{y} = 0$ solution with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have to solve the following problem:

$yu_{yy} + u_{y} = 0$

$u(x, 1) = x^{2}$

$u(x, e) = 1$

I have tried first taking one $\partial u/\partial y$ and integrating but I obtain a function that depends on $y$ and then I have to do another integration on $y$ but now I have to integrate $u$, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Let us substitute $v = u_y$ in the differential equation, so that $y v_y + v = 0$ or maybe $v_y/v = -1/y$. This is a (separable) Cauchy-Euler differential equation w.r.t. $y$, which solution reads $v(x,y) = c_1(x)/y$. Integration w.r.t. $y$ then yields
$$
u(x,y) = c_1(x)\ln y + c_2(x) \, .
$$
Using the boundary conditions, we have
\begin{aligned}
u(x,1) &= c_2(x) = x^2 \\
u(x,e) &= c_1(x) + c_2(x) = 1
\end{aligned}
from which we can conclude.

Answer (score 1):

$$yu_{yy} + u_{y} = 0$$
$$yu''+u'=0$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(yu')'=0$$
Integrate twice.
$$yu'=c_1(x)$$
$$u'=\dfrac {c_1(x)}y$$
integrate again:
$$u(x,y)= {c_1(x)} \ln |y|+c_2(x)$$